# vb.net documentation for generics is not showing the type of T

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, documentation

I have a method that returns an ObservableCollection of an interface called IExcelSheetTypeDto.
I'm trying to document it but when i add a cref to ObservableCollection(Of IExcelSheetTypeDto) it shows ObservableCollection(Of T) in the method description

```
''' <summary>
''' Method explanation
''' </summary>
''' <returns>
''' <see cref="ObservableCollection(Of IExcelSheetTypeDto)"/>
''' </returns>
```

and that's what it shows when I hover over the method:
[image]

Is it possible to show the real type instead of T? If so how can I do that ?

Comment: Can't seem to replicate your error. Did you rebuild your solution? (Notice: I tested it with c#, don't know vb.net to well)

Comment: I just tried it in VB and I can't replicate it either. I am using ReSharper, so I'm not sure whether that would make a difference.

Comment: Of course that's what you see. Until you actually get to a method call site, that `T` could be **anything**, even if your xml comments say otherwise. They are ultimately just comments, after all. If you really want to return something else more specific involving `IExcelSheetDto`, you should declare it that way.

Comment: I checked again and I see what you're saying now. I was looking in the wrong place. I can confirm that I see the same behaviour. I tried with an interface and a concrete class and they both showed as just `T`.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, it's really about the method though. It's about the documentation. You can type anything you like into that `<returns>` element and that literal text will be displayed in the tooltip that pops up when you mouse over the method, but if you add a `<see cref>` element for a generic type - any generic type, whether it's the same as the return type or not - with it's generic type parameter set, the tooltip ignores that type parameter and just displays `T`.

Comment: Are you saying that there is no way to make it show OnservableCollection( Of ISomeEnterface) in the tooltip?